# Prove that the Zolotarev symbol is the same as Legendre and Jacobi symbols

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity

There are only a handful of resources that discuss the Zolotarev proof of the quadratic reciprocity law.  Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $a \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, and $(a, n) = 1$.  We can define a permutation

$$ T: x \mapsto ax \pmod n. $$

The Zolotarev symbol

$$ \left( \frac{a}{n} \right) $$

is defined to be the sign of the permutation $T$.  Why is this the same as the Legendre symbol?

---

I tried to prove this by dividing the work into two cases:

- If $a = b^2 \pmod n$, then the map $T_b: x \mapsto bx \pmod n$ has an *even* number of cycles.
- If $a \neq x^2 \pmod n$, then the permutation $T_a$ *must* have an odd number of cycles of even length.

I am not sure that last assertion is true.  It is mostly just wishful thinking.

---

Zolotarev's lemma seems to have been left as an exercise in Conway's book on [Quadratic Forms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883850303).  There are other resources which take a less whimsical route:

- [[1](https://math.colorado.edu/~rohi1040/expository/quad_recip.pdf)] Proofs of QR
- [[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zolotarev's_lemma)] Wikipedia
- [[3](http://www.numdam.org/item/NAM_1872_2_11__354_0)]  Nouvelle démonstration de la loi de réciprocité de Legendre (Zolotareff)

Comment: The Legendre symbol is only defined when the bottom number is an odd prime ... so do you mean to restrict $n$ to odd primes? In any event, the size of every cycle of $T$ is exactly the order of $a$ modulo $n$, so the number of cycles is $\phi(n)$ divided by this order. When $n$ is an odd prime, you can correlate whether this quotient is even/odd with whether $a$ is/isn't a quadratic residue, using the fact that a primitive root exists.

Answer (score 1):

The proof that the [Zolotarev symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zolotarev%27s_lemma) is the same as the [Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol) is given at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zolotarev%27s_lemma) and also in [another document as Lemma 1](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~hlm/nzm/quadrec.pdf).

The proof that the Zolotarev symbol is the same as the [Jacobi symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_symbol) is given in five pages in that same document.